# Error writing data with foreign key in postgresql python

Tags: postgresql

After parsing, I try to place the data in two tables. For each event in the CirculationData table, 15 events must be recorded in EventData.
models.py

```
class CirculationData(models.Model):
    number_circulation = 
    models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


class EventData(models.Model):
    circulation = models.ForeignKey(CirculationData, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="events")
    number = models.IntegerField()
    match = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    liga = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    score = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    result = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

script

```
<not significant start of script>
number_circulation = int(data_1.find_all("td")[1].text)
status = data_2.find("span").text
datetime = translate_in_datetime(data_1.find_all("td")[5].text)

data_1 = [number_circulation, status, datetime]

cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO app_circulationdata(number_circulation, status, 
              datetime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", data_1)
conn.commit()

for value in soup.find_all("tr", class_="line"):
    number = int(value.find("td").text)
    match = value.find("div", class_="text-nowrap font-weight- 
             bold").text.strip()
    liga = value.find("p").text
    score = value.find_all("td")[6].text
    result = value.find_all("td")[7].text

    cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO app_eventdata (number, match, liga, score, 
           result, circulation_id)"
           " VALUES (number, match, liga, score, result, 
           number_circulation)")

    conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

There is an entry in CirculationData, and then the error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/", line 61, in 
cursor.execute(
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "number_circulation"
does not exist
LINE 1: ...nt_pool_2, percent_book_2, score, result) VALUES (number_cir..."

Comment: Could you please post all relevant information in one place, in plain text?

Comment: The first time I post a question, it doesn't quite work out yet. It seems to have been edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. I searched for a long time and found it.

```
cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO app_eventdata (circulation_id, num, match, liga, 
             score, result)"
            " VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (number_circulation, numb, match, liga, score, result)
        )
```